# Swift ! operator on types

Tags: swift, types

I assume this is a question that's been asked a million times, but Googling it results in explanation of the logical ! operator.

I've come across these 2 code examples:

```
class RetainCycle {
    var closure: (() -> Void)! // THIS LINE
    var string = "Hello"

    init() {
        closure = {
            self.string = "Hello, World!"
        }
    }
}
```

AND:

```
class B: A {

    convenience init(str : String) {
        self.init(num: Int(str)!) // THIS LINE
    }

    func haveFun() {
        print("Woo hoo!")
    }
}
```

The examples themselves aren't really relevant, they were both talking about different subject, but in both cases there's the syntax of "!"

In the second example I'm pretty sure it means unwrapping the value returned from Int(), as I assume it returns a nillable value, but what does it mean in the first one?

Thanks, Avi.

Comment: Implicitly unwrapped optionals are used whenever you are absolutely, positively sure that your application will not make any attempt to get an optional’s value before it has been set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first case it makes that when you use `closure` somewhere else in the code you don't need to use `?` because Xcode assumes it is will not be nil, the same is when you connect some UI element from storyboard to code it saves outlet already unwrapped with `!` at the end

Comment: So closure CAN be set to nil in this case? And what happens if someone tries to use it when it's nil? Exception is thrown?

Comment: It can be nil, but when you are using it and it will be nil the app will crash